# I want to make login application in android using java as a web server and pass the controls values in java without query string

Tags: java, android, web-services, android-volley

I want to create login page in android ,for web services i have choosen java,so i want to fetch data in json format(i have written the code in java),now for login i want to store success if login successful else fail.my problem is that i want to pass username and password from controls in android to java how should i do that i am always getting "failed" because everytime the isUser() called null values are passed inside the functoion though my credentials are correct

MyClass.java

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONString;

class MyClass {
   Connection con = null;
     Statement stmt = null;
     ResultSet rs = null;
int mobno;String passwd;
private static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
private static final String DATABASE_URL = 
"jdbc:mysql://localhost/psamajdb";
private static final String USERNAME = "root";
private static final String PASSWORD = "";
MyClass(){
    this.passwd=passwd;
    this.mobno=mobno;       
   try {
        Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
    stmt=con.createStatement();

   } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception e  = " + e);
    }}

   public JSONArray convertToJson(ResultSet rs) throws Exception{
               JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    while (rs.next()) {
        int total_rows = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < total_rows; i++) {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            obj.put(rs.getMetaData().getColumnLabel(i + 1)
                    .toLowerCase(), rs.getObject(i + 1));
            jsonArray.put(obj);
        }
    }
    return jsonArray;
   }
   public String[] jsonToString(JSONArray arr){
       if(arr==null)
       {
           return null;
       }
       String[] str1=new String[arr.length()];
       for (int i = 0; i < str1.length; i++) {
           str1[i]=arr.optString(i);

       }
       return str1;

   }

public JSONObject  isUser(int Mobno,String Passwd){
Mobno=mobno;
Passwd=passwd;
System.out.println(mobno);
    System.out.println(passwd);
JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
     String qry="select id from info where mobno="+Mobno+" and 
    passwd="+"'"+Passwd+"'";
        PreparedStatement pst;
      try {
                  stmt=con.createStatement();
                 rs=stmt.executeQuery(qry);

        if(rs.next())
        {
            System.out.println("Successful");
            String msg="success";
            String value="Success";
           obj=generateJson(msg,value);
        }else
        {
            System.out.println("Failed");
            String msg="failed";
            String value="Failed";
            obj=generateJson(msg,value);

        }
      } catch (SQLException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(MyServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, 
    null, ex);
      }
      return obj;

}

private JSONObject generateJson(String msg, String value) {
     JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
    if(value.equals("Success"))
    {
        try {
            obj.put(msg, value);
        } catch (JSONException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, 
null, ex);
        }
    }else{

           try {
            obj.put(msg, value);
        } catch (JSONException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, 
null, ex);
        }
    }
    return obj;  
}
}
```

MyServlet.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
 import javax.servlet.ServletException;
 import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
 import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONString;
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/MyServlet"})
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
String data;
  private static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
private static final String DATABASE_URL = 
"jdbc:mysql://localhost/testdb";
private static final String USERNAME = "root";
private static final String PASSWORD = "";
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, 
HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet MyServlet</title>");            
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        doPost(request, response);         
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }
}
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}


@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
                 PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
     int mobno;
     String passwd;          
     Connection con = null;
     Statement stmt = null;
     ResultSet rs = null;
     try{   
           MyClass obj=new MyClass();
           mobno=obj.mobno;
           passwd=obj.passwd;
           System.out.println("here");
           JSONObject jobj=obj.isUser(mobno, passwd);
       out.println(jobj);
         System.out.println(jobj);
     }catch(Exception e){
      out.println(e);
     }    
}
@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}// </editor-fold>



}
```

Comment: How is the username and password passed from the app?  A BASIC Auth header, or POSTed values?  The code doesn't show getting the username and password from the request - just creating a new instance of MyClass, with no apparent connection to the request.  Also, using concatenation to build a query is open to SQL Injection attack - use a PreparedStatement to set query parameters. Also, the code indicates the password is stored as plain text. Also, it's not clear if the connection, statement, and resultset are ever properly closed.

Comment: i have added my complete MyClass.java file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor for `MyClass` currently looks like this:

```
MyClass()    {
    this.passwd = passwd;  // logic error
    this.mobno = mobno;    // logic error

    ... other lines omitted
}
```

In the context of the constructor, `this.passwd` and `passwd` refer to the same object.  Since it's within the constructor the value is null.  Check your IDE or compiler for warnings.  Same with the other line.

So you probably want to make `passwd` and `mobno` as parameters for the constructor like this:

```
MyClass(String passwd, int mobno)    {
    this.passwd = passwd;
    this.mobno = mobno;

    ... other lines omitted
}
```

to properly assign the values.  The `request` will need to be interrogated to get those values so a new `MyClass` instance can be properly created.  Interrogating the request depends on how the values were sent from the app.

Comment: i have corrected my constructor,now i am confused that   what values for username,passwd should i initialize with?

Comment: Use the values which were POSTed from the app.

Comment: but how should i get those values ??

Comment: The app could POST as a header (usually a BASIC Auth) or as key/value attributes.  The values are then available through the `request`.  Lots of examples on the web.